# How do I make a SharePoint Web Part work when installed on a SharePoint instance that uses a vanity URL?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, error

My team has developed a SharePoint integration that uses the SharePoint Web Part framework to embed a page from our application on a SharePoint page.

This is working well for most of our customers, but we have one customer using a "vanity URL" for their SharePoint instance (essentially, instead of `https://something.sharepoint.com`, their domain for SharePoint is `https://sp-cloud.companyName.org`).

When the customer clicks to add a new Web Part and selects our app, a new Web Part is created that says only "404 FILE NOT FOUND". Inspecting the browser's network tab in dev tools reveals that a request was made to `https://something.sharepoint.com/.../newWebPartInstanceId=...&windowOrigin=https://sp-cloud.companyName.org...`.

So the request appears to be going to the wrong domain, but likely what the domain would have been if not for the vanity URL. As near as I can tell, this is Microsoft making a (failing) request to Microsoft, and I don't see anywhere that a request is making it to my team's servers, so I'm not sure what can be done on my end to fix this.

Is there a way to configure the Web Part/manifest to use the correct domain?